# Bit masking for I2C writes?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This has probably already been asked but I'm having trouble understanding how to do masking when writing using I2C. Say I have a function called `i2c_update` with the following parameters:

```
dev Pointer to the device structure for the driver instance.
dev_addr    Address of the I2C device for updating.
reg_addr    Address of the internal register being updated.
mask    Bitmask for updating internal register.
value   Value for updating internal register.
```

I know how to deal with the `dev, dev_addr and reg_addr` but I'm confused on how to mask and what value to use. For example, if `0x00000111` is at the register I want to modify currently and I want to change it to `0x01000000` what `mask` and what `value` would I want to use?

Thanks!

edit: [this is the link of the api I'm using](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/apidoc/latest/group__i2c__interface_ga2a1973cce3f394f0c2654aefdcaceee0.html)

Comment: It is impossible to tell for sure without seeing the function implementation/documentation. But I would *assume* that it is doing something like `new_value = (old_value & mask) | value;`. But it also could be `new_value = (old_value & ~mask) | value;`.  Or maybe even something like `new_value = (old_value & mask) | (value & mask)`This is why the info provided is not sufficient.

Comment: We need to know the semantics of the `mask` parameter. Is it the bits you want to keep? Is it the bits you want to modify? It's also helpful to know the semantics of `value`. For example, is it guaranteed to be zero for bits you don't want to modify? Or do you have to mask off the bits you don't want to change?

Comment: Also, your example is unhelpful because we can't tell what you want the code to do if the value of the register is something other than `0x00000111`. For example, if you say "the value is now 7 and I want to change it to 8", that could mean you always wants to set the value to 8 but it could mean you want to add one to the value. So you have to tell us the logic for any current value or we can't tell you how to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've included a link to the api documentation. To be honest, I think the documentation is confusing which is why I'm wondering if anyone knows

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I put a link to the api in my description. I want to modify certain bits without changing others so I'm wondering what my mask and value should be

Comment: @innyme Then we need to know which bits you want to modify and which bits you want to leave alone. Presumably, the `mask` should be the bits you want to modify. For example, we can't tell from your question whether you want to zero the most significant bit or leave it alone. So how can we tell you what mask to use?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This is just an example, but say the current value of the register is 0x00000111 and I want to change it to 0x01000000.

Comment: @innyme That's not helpful because we can't tell what you actually want to do. For example, do you want to set the second bit to 1 or do you want to flip the second bit? Both could get you from 0x00000111 to 0x0100000. Do you want to set the third bit from the right to zero or do you want to leave it alone? How can we tell?

Answer (score 0):

It takes 5 minutes to find the function in the project repo

```
static inline int i2c_reg_update_byte(struct device *dev, uint8_t dev_addr,
                      uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t mask,
                      uint8_t value)
{
    uint8_t old_value, new_value;
    int rc;

    rc = i2c_reg_read_byte(dev, dev_addr, reg_addr, &old_value);
    if (rc != 0) {
        return rc;
    }

    new_value = (old_value & ~mask) | (value & mask);
    if (new_value == old_value) {
        return 0;
    }

    return i2c_reg_write_byte(dev, dev_addr, reg_addr, new_value);
}
```

`new_value = (old_value & ~mask) | (value & mask);` :

`old_value & ~mask` - clears masked bits

`value & mask` clears all other bits except the mask

`|` sets the cleared bits in the `old_value` with the bits left in the `value`

Do you need more explanation? If yes it is the time to learn a bit bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked up the Zephyr project source code and found the implementation of the function [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/zephyr/latest/source/include/drivers/i2c.h#L611):

```
static inline int i2c_reg_update_byte(struct device *dev, u8_t dev_addr,
                      u8_t reg_addr, u8_t mask,
                      u8_t value)
{
    u8_t old_value, new_value;
    int rc;

    rc = i2c_reg_read_byte(dev, dev_addr, reg_addr, &old_value);
    if (rc != 0) {
        return rc;
    }

    new_value = (old_value & ~mask) | (value & mask);
    if (new_value == old_value) {
        return 0;
    }

    return i2c_reg_write_byte(dev, dev_addr, reg_addr, new_value);
}
```

As you can see the net action is

```
new_value = (old_value & ~mask) | (value & mask);
```

So it will only assign the bits of `value` corresponding to ones in the `mask` to the `new_value`, and the rest will remain same as `old_value`.